# View image selected from file-system on client-side before upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an input tag on a form for selecting images to upload.

```
<div id="lowresDemo">
    <img src="some-url" />
</div>
<input type="file" id="FileToUpload" name="FileToUpload" />
```

I've attempted to change the a thumbnail displayed on the form next to the input to affirm to the user that their selection was the intended with the following jquery code:

```
$('#FileToUpload').change(function () {
    $('#lowresDemo img').attr('src', $(this).val());
});
```

...this doesn't work in any browser, for browser security reasons I beleieve (as I remember from the last time I did something like this years ago).

**QUESTION**:
Is there a way to present the user's choice of image before they submit the form -- and not just the filepath+name of the value in the input field, but a thumbnail showing the file they've selected?

Or does modern browser security prevent this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's possible with the File API (IE does not support the File API)

```
<input type="file">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").change(function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            img.src = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        $("input").after(img);
    }
});
    });
</script>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ugPDx/

Comment: Fixed, used append before which added the image into the input field making it not vvisible.

Comment: This appears to only work in Chrome, Fails in IE and Firefox 15.

Comment: I've modified the fiddle to work on Firefox, probably works on IE9, but untested:  http://jsfiddle.net/ugPDx/825/

Comment: File API is supported by IE10 and 11. Users of prior versions should just stop dragging us behind :)

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, I didn't think it would be possible. It is working in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to perform the operation before uploading the picture.

But think of it in a different way - the user "doesn' care" if the picture is already uploaded - you could show the thumbnail after they've uploaded, and show a confirm checkbox. Gmail does this with their email attachments - as soon as you selected the file to attach, the upload starts. But the user always has the option to uncheck the file, and it won't be included in the email.

Comment: edit: @Peeter's html5 file api (http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) is very interesting. too bad no cross browser support.