# Show image before actually uploading it

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm using `filefield` to upload image to server on my form and that works fine.

But can I somehow immediately after user uses `browse` button load that image into `image` field (kind of as a preview) ? Since I have no access to real full path, I didn't find a way to do that...

**Edit:**
Thanks to Shayan I managed to get proper code for this:

(in `fileupload` componentes `change` event):

```
    var file = uploader.fileInputEl.dom.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
        form.down('#imgLogo').setSrc(evt.target.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [View image selected from file-system on client-side before upload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250704/view-image-selected-from-file-system-on-client-side-before-upload)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use FileReader Api and do it...

```
    <script>
    var file=new FileReader();
file.readAsDataUrl(fileInput.files[0]);
file.onload=function(evt){
var img=document.getElementById("myimage");
img.src=evt.target.result;
}


    </script>
```

Comment: Not quite what I needed in extjs, but pointed me in right direction, thanks

Comment: @Marin, can you upload the answer u needed for extjs? Im running into same problem.