# Multiple Files - Preview in DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, input

Can someone help me out here.

If I have 4 Inputs of type "file", and 4 div's with no content.

```
<div>
    <input type="file" name="bestand_een" class="" value="">
    <input type="file" name="bestand_twee" class="" value="">
    <input type="file" name="bestand_drie" class="" value="">
    <input type="file" name="bestand_vier" class="" value="">
</div>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
```

How can I show chosen image from input 1 in div 1 and so on?
(I need 4 inputs not 1 input and each chosen image to a div)

Comment: You want to display a file on the local file system in a webpage?

Comment: Yes show chosen image directly in one of the div's

Comment: If this is going to be a page on a website, then the image has to be accessible to the page. That means that the image has to be uploaded onto the server that is running the website. That is not possible in JavaScript and HTML. You have to have an server side programming language such as PHP or .NET to retrieve the uploaded file and store it on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250704/view-image-selected-from-file-system-on-client-side-before-upload

Comment: Isn't it possible to just show chosen image in the input in one of the divs. Like a file reader does?

Comment: it can only be done via FileSystemAPI but its not supported by all the browsers.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function readURL(input, ndx) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(".out").eq(ndx).css({
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                "background-image": "url("+e.target.result+")",
                "background-size": "100% 100%",
                "background-repeat": "no-repeat"
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("input[type=file]").change(function(){
    readURL(this, $(this).index());
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="file" name="bestand_een" class="" value="">
    <input type="file" name="bestand_twee" class="" value="">
    <input type="file" name="bestand_drie" class="" value="">
    <input type="file" name="bestand_vier" class="" value="">
</div>

<div id="one" class="out"></div>
<div id="two" class="out"></div>
<div id="three" class="out"></div>
<div id="four" class="out"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```